# Showing error "Files should not contain characters before "<?php" in sonarQube for laravel blade template files

Tags: php, laravel-4, sonarqube, standards

I'm developing an application using Laravel framework. When I check coding standard via sonarQube quality analysis tool, it showing error like "Files should not contain characters before "

I'm using code to include header files via "@section('header')". How can we fix the issue? After extends it shows error.

```
@extends('layouts.user') 
@section('content')
<ul class="breadcrumb">
    <li>{{trans('user.home')}}</li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li>{{ trans("user.heading") }}</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Comment: please show the code where it's failing.

Comment: I updated in my post. please check above images and code

Comment: I guess in your case this rule is not applicable, and actually it should not be activated by default: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPHP-427.